# Error when running mcp in eclipse and I can't fix it

Tags: java, minecraft

```
[17:03:44] [Client thread/INFO]: (Session ID is token:0:Player61)
[17:03:45] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.2
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x00007fff2fc42abc, pid=38089, tid=0x0000000000000e03
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_291-b10) (build 1.8.0_291-b10)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.291-b10 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [AppKit+0x3e5abc]  -[NSOpenGLContext setView:]+0xe5
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/palmtrww/Desktop/tee/jars/hs_err_pid38089.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

I'm on mac catilina version 10.15.7 and when I run mcp inside of eclipse i get this error

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can run `ulimit -c unlimited` such as suggested in the error message.

Then, I suggest you to upgrade your JVM.

Finally, if the error already appear, you can report it to Java dev [here](http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp).

PS: Next time, don't forget to show the file `/Users/palmtrww/Desktop/tee/jars/hs_err_pid38089.log`.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to downgrade your Java version or downgrade your Eclipse IDE to a version that supports Java 8.